# DOMException: Invalid security origin - trying to access camera in chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, webcam

I have react JS extension using react-webcam to access camera and make screenshots. In normal webapp it works ok but inside chrome extension, trying to access camera through:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
.then(function(stream) {
  console.log(stream)
})
.catch(function(err) {
 console.log(err)
});
```

I get DOMException: Invalid security origin in console. Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: Permissions - my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "__MSG_peeps_name__ DEV",
    "description": "__MSG_peeps_description__",
    "version": "4.0.0",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "/icons/icon_48.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "/icons/icon_16.png",
        "32": "/icons/icon_32.png",
        "48": "/icons/icon_48.png",
        "64": "/icons/icon_64.png",
        "128": "/icons/icon_128.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "app/*",
        "/images/*",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": ["page.html"]
    },
    "commands": {
        "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+P"
            }
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTabs",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "identity",
        "videoCapture",
        "identity.email",        
        "chrome-extension://*"
    ],
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "email",
            "profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
        ]
    },
    "key":"12345
}
```

Comment: Have you added `videoCapture` permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes, just now added but still error remains the same - Invalid Security Origin. I pasted my manifest.json

Comment: 'videoCapture' is only allowed for packaged apps, not for extension.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this documentation about [permissions with warnings in `manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permission_warnings), you must add:

> "**`contentSettings`**"
>
> - Grants your extension access to the `chrome.contentSettings` API.
> - Change your settings that control websites' access to features such as cookies, JavaScript, plugins, geolocation, microphone, **camera** etc.

Comment: Tried it. My manifest looks like this:
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "identity",
        "contentSettings",
        "videoCapture",
        "identity.email", 
    ],
And upon loading build as new extension in chrome, i get error:
'videoCapture' is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension.
Removed the 'videoCapture' but still DOMException: Invalid security origin